# How can the python script in Plone be displayed as a page?

Tags: plone

I am using Plone 5. What I am trying to do is to add a page on my website using a python script that retrieves some data from the website and will create a survey from that data. I wrote some code and that is displayed as a blank page when testing, but how do you actually make it be a part of you website so it is displayed there?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to implement a BrowserView.
This is fully documented here: http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/browserviews.html#creating-a-view

A simpler alternative could be to use Rapido: http://rapidoplone.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks! I am using Rapido and I did the same as in the tutorial for rating app using Rapido, but it is not displayed on the page, instead, it gives me an error message:  
-Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
-Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
*Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
*Module rapido.plone.browser.views, line 121, in __call__
*Modulerapido.plone.browser.views, line 58, in content
*Module rapido.display, line 51, in GET  
  NotAllowed.  
I would be grateful if you could point me where things went wrong. Thanks!

Comment: The `NotAllowed` error is what you get when you call a badly formatted Rapido URL. In your case, you have made a GET on `@@rapido/your_app/something_bad` (instead of `something_bad `, you should have `block` or `record`, there is nothing else allowed).